# Group by when condition is not just by row in Python Pandas

Tags: python, performance, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes one at the lower level and one that summarizes the data at a higher level. I'm trying to add a new column to the summary table that sums the total spending of all people who are fans of a particular sport. IE in the summary row of soccer I do NOT want to sum the total soccer spending, but the total sports spending of anyone who spends anything on soccer.  
[image]

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Person': [1,2,3,3,3],
                   'Sport': ['Soccer','Tennis','Tennis','Football','Soccer'],
                  'Ticket_Cost': [10,20,10,10,20]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Sport': ['Soccer','Tennis','Football']})
```

I can currently do this in many steps, but I'm sure there is a more efficient/quicker way.  Here is how I currently do it.

```
#Calculate the total spend for each person in an temporary dataframe
df_intermediate = df.groupby(['Person'])['Ticket_Cost'].sum()
df_intermediate= df_intermediate.rename("Total_Sports_Spend")
```

Person  Total_Sports_Spend
1   10
2   20
3   40

```
#place this total in the detailed table
df = pd.merge(df,df_intermediate,how='left',on='Person')
```

[image]

```
#Create a second temporary dataframe
df_intermediate2 = df.groupby(['Sport'])['Total_Sports_Spend'].sum()
```

Sport   Total_Sports_Spend 
Football    40
Soccer  50
Tennis  60

```
#Merge this table with the summary table
df2 = pd.merge(df2,df_intermediate2,how='left',on='Sport')
```

Sport    Total_Sports_Spend
0   Soccer  50
1   Tennis  60
2   Football    40

Finally, I clean up the temporary dataframes and remove the extra column from the detailed table. I'm sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to rotate your DataFrame in 2D:

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index = 'Person', columns = 'Sport', values = 'Ticket_Cost')
```

You get

```
Sport   Football    Soccer  Tennis
Person          
     1  NaN         10.0    NaN
     2  NaN         NaN     20.0
     3  10.0        20.0    10.0
```

Now you can compute the total spending per person:

```
total = df2.sum(axis=1)
```

which is

```
Person
1    10.0
2    20.0
3    40.0
dtype: float64
```

Finally you place the total spending values of `total` in the cells of `df2` where the cell has a positive value:

```
df3 = (df2>0).mul(total, axis=0)
```

which is here:

```
Sport   Football    Soccer  Tennis
Person          
     1  0.0     10.0    0.0
     2  0.0     0.0     20.0
     3  40.0    40.0    40.0
```

Finally you just have to sum along columns to get what you want:

```
spending = df3.sum(axis=0)
```

and will get what you expect.

Comment: This method works and it's good to have multiple approaches.  However, it takes 50% more time than the original method and it's just as many steps.  
For clarity df2 should have a different name (eg dfb), this name was already used in the problem statement.